# Adding field values from feature class into empty field of another feature class using append

Tags: arcpy, esri-geodatabase, feature-class, append

I am attempting to add a feature class ("dis.shp") into an empty feature class("fc.shp") in a geodatabase using Python script.  I have had success with the code below.  However, I also would like to add values from dis.shp's field "GRIDCODE" into fc.shp's field "Classes".  I have been playing around with append but am not having any luck.  Any suggestions?

```
arcpy.Append_management(dis, fc , schemaType, fieldMappings, subtype)
```

Comment: Would an arcpy cursor, like an [Update Cursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018v00000064000000) do what you want?

Comment: simple data loader i think would be easiest way to do this.  append in test mode may work, in no test it will keep the schema of the data set being appended to.

Comment: fc.shp is a bad name for something in FGDB

Answer (score 1):

I believe with the append tool both source and destination table schemas have to be the same (field names/types).  Here are some options:

1. Use the Merge tool, select features, and field calculate (not recommended since you have to be careful what you have selected before calculating)
2. Make sure the table schemas are the same between source and destination tables and use append tool
3. Convert destination shp to gdb fc, right click on the destination fc and select Data>Load and manually set the fields between source and destination tables and import
4. Alternatively, you could use a combination of embedded search and insert cursors to iterate through source and insert into destination (careful of the field mapping here too)